# Python for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a contacts program and I have to write some information to txt file.
I create a list and two dictionaries

```
name = ['charles', 'frank', 'chris']
phonenumbers = {'charles' : '12345', 'frank' : '23456', 'chris' : '34567'}
emails = {'charles' : '12345@qq.com', 'frank' : '23456@qq.com', 'chris' : '34567@qq.com'}
```

and I have two variables

```
ld_names = names, phonenumbers, emails
files = ('name_file.txt', 'phonenumber_file.txt', 'emails.txt')
```

I want to get a result like this

```
name_file.txt
['charles', 'frank', 'chris']
phonenumber_file.txt
{'charles': '12345', 'frank': '23456', 'chris': '34567'}
emails.txt
{'charles': '12345@qq.com', 'frank': '23456@qq.com', 'chris': '34567@qq.com'}
```

as you can see i have 3 txt files. it's too verbose if I write them one by one.
and I try to use for loop

```
for file in files:
    for ld_name in ld_names:
        print(ld_name)
    print(file
```

this is the code i try to write to the files.

```
    while True:
        mes = input('please press your key:')
        if mes == 'quit':
            for file in files:
                with open(file, 'ab') as f:
                    for ld_name in ld_names:
                    pickle.dump(ld_name, f) 
                    f.close()
            break
```

but the result is not I want to get

Comment: could you explain it more? i have no idea what are you trying to do! do you want them to write to a txt file?

Comment: yes, i am trying to write a contact program and i need to write data of list & dicts to a file. as you can see i have 3 files and it's verbose if i try to write them one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dump json, you should use `json` instead of `pickle`. And if you are certain that the indexes of `ld_names` and `files` matches, then you can use `enumerate` with the files. Otherwise, I suggest using a `dict` of files (i.e `{file: data, ...}`). Try this sample code;

```
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['charles', 'frank', 'chris']
    phonenumbers = {'charles': '12345', 'frank': '23456', 'chris': '34567'}
    emails = {'charles': '12345@qq.com', 'frank': '23456@qq.com', 'chris': '34567@qq.com'}

    ld_names = names, phonenumbers, emails
    files = ('name_file.txt', 'phonenumber_file.txt', 'emails.txt')

    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        with open(file, 'ab') as f:
            json.dump(ld_names[i], f)
            f.close()
            pass
        pass
```

Comment: ha, i am sorry for accept your answer late because i don't know and i don't have enough reputation to vote it up :(  i am sorry about that..